# converting the data to json format in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, haml

My requirement is to implement auto complete feature in my rails application. I need to convert the @testers in my controller code below to json format.

```
def new
  @release = Release.new
  @ic_ids = params[:ic_ids] ? params[:ic_ids] : []
  @testers = User.find_by_sql("select * from users where id in(select user_id from user_role_assignments where role_id in (select id from roles where name like 'Tester')) order by name").paginate(:page=>params[:page],:per_page=>30)   
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @release }
  end
end
```

In my view code i tried this:

```
%td.grid.full_panels
    -table_panel "Assign Testers" do
      %table
        %th Name
        -puts "testers=#{@testers}"
        = form.label :tester_tokens, "Testers" 
        = form.text_field :tester_tokens,:class => 'autocomplete'
 :javascript
  data = #{testers.to_json}
```

I am getting undefined for data.

Please help me out here.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a json source you can add `format.json` to the respond_to loop liek this:

```
def index
     @objects=Model.where("name LIKE ?", "%params[:q]%") || Model.all
     respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render :json => @objects.map(&:attributes) }
     end
end
```

If you dont want to extract all the data `only` and `except` options are available. You should be able to use this for the most autocomplete plugins!

By adding the `q` data you will be able to demarcate the results by given pattern.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks a lot for taking time to answer me. In my case the @testers is already extracted from different tables with an sql query.so please help me with how to use it in the above format. Also help with how to use this in .js file?

Comment: also please let me know as to where to pass the "q" parameter

Comment: You can also render any other data just replce @objects with any other array of objects that should be rendered with json. If you simply extract these things without the possibilite to filter `q`isnt needed!

Comment: Hi David I changed my code to  @users=User.all
     respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render :json => @users.map(&:attributes) }  Please help me with how to use this json in the jquery file
    end

Answer (score 1):

Why the `data =`? That is invalid javascript, as far as I can see.

The correct HAML syntax would be:

```
:javascript
  #{testers.to_json}
```

Comment: hi berkes, thanks a lot for answering me. Please help me with how to use this passed json in my js script

Comment: In your code, you tried to print the json directly within your HTML; but failed to do so, because of wrong HAML. My answer simply a fix for what you try to achieve. It appears you are trying something else. Please update your answer with a more high-level target: what are you trying to achieve. Rather then a detailed question on a certain error you got.

Comment: I am not trying to print the json.I am trying to pass the converted json to the .js file

Comment: Then look at @davidb's answer. He or she explains how to use formatters to create a json representation of your data on a RESTfull url.